# handling states of music player with properties of type:Function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm not really sure if i framed the question right. 
I've been using a music player plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/music_player) to handle playback, but i'm not sure how to use states (eg: *onIsPlaying* or *onDuration* or *onPlayNext* etc) because they have a type of **Function**.
I basically want to use these in an *onTap* for handling playback functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set them

```
onDuration = (Duration duration){//do something}

onPaused= (){//paused do something}
```